# Create index for last two digits of number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing

I have a massive table in which I can't do any more partitioning or sub-partitioning, nor am allowed to do any alter. I want to query its records by batches, and thought a good way would be using the last two digits from the account numbers (wouldn't have any other field splitting records as evenly).

I guess I'd need to at least index that somehow (remember I can't alter table to add a virtual column either).

Is there any kind of index to be used in such situation?

I am using Oracle 11gR2

Comment: A function-based index might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [function based index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS254):

```
create index two_digits_idx on table_name (substr(account_number, -2));
```

This index will work only in queries like that:

```
select ...
  from table_name t ...
 where substr(account_number, -2) = '25' -- or any other two digits
```

For using index, you need to use in a query the same expression like in an index.